# Momentarily Comoving Reference Frame Question

Tags: special-relativity

Consider a reference frame $S'$ moving with constant velocity $\vec{V}$ relative to a second nonrotating reference frame $S$. Also consider a particle moving along a trajectory $\vec{r}$ with perhaps variable velocity $\vec{u}=\dot{\vec{r}}$, both relative to $S$, with the corresponding quantities $\vec{r}\thinspace'$ and $\vec{u}\thinspace'$ relative to $S'$.

The general Lorentz transformation can be written in the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{r}\thinspace'\\
t'
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma\hat{e}_v\hat{e}_v^T+\hat{e}\hat{e}^T+\hat{e}_1\hat{e}_1^T&-\gamma\vec{V}\\
-\gamma\vec{V}^T/c^2&\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{r}\\
t
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\vec{V}=V\hat{e}_v$ and $\hat{e},\hat{e}_1$ are unit vectors perpendicular to $\vec{V}$ chosen to complete a right handed orthonormal basis, all treated here as column matrices. As usual, $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-V^2/c^2}$.

After straightforward but somewhat involved algebraic manipulation, one derives the relation
$$
\sqrt{1-u'^2}=\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\gamma\left[1-\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{V}}{c^2}\right]}.
$$
By differentiating the Lorentz transformation we derive $dt'=\gamma\left[1-\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{V}}{c^2}\right]dt$. Now suppose that at some instant $t_0$ we have $\vec{u}(t_0)=\vec{V}$. Then $\vec{u}\thinspace'(t_0)=0$ and so $dt'=\sqrt{\left[1-\frac{V^2}{c^2}\right]}dt$---at that instant $t_0$. Most textbooks now define $d\tau=dt'=\sqrt{1-V^2/c^2}dt$ and claim it to be the "proper" time that a clock attached to the moving particle would read, even integrating it to get a total elapsed ``proper time.''

So much for the background. Here is my question. Since $dt'$ is the time increment measured by a clock that is stationary in the reference frame $S'$---which moves with constant velocity $\vec{V}$---why should I assume that $dt'$ is also the incremental time measured on a clock moving with the (possibly accelerating)  particle as assumed by the aforementioned texts?

Comment: First, I guess you meant $\sqrt{1-u'^2/c^2} = \sqrt{1-u^2/c^2} /\gamma/ (1-\vec{u}\cdot\vec{V}/c^2)$. Second, when $\vec{u}(t_0) = \vec{V}$, $dt' = \gamma (1 - \beta^2) dt = \sqrt{1-\beta^2} dt$, not $dt' = (1-\beta^2) dt$. So $d\tau = dt'$ at $t = t_0$ because at this instance the $S'$ frame matches the instantaneous frame of the particle, regardless of the particle's acceleration.

Comment: udrv: Thanks for catching the typos. Corrections made in original post.